# g:javascript working in firefox but not in chrome

Tags: javascript, grails, gsp

this works perfectly as I want it to in Firefox, but it does not work in Chrome. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

```
<g:javascript>
    function selectedStatus()
    {
      var index = j("#statusId");
      if(${statusValue} = ${Status.getAllEnums()})
      {
        index.selectedIndex = ${statusValue};
      }
    }
</g:javascript>
```

I am passing a value for a users status from a controller to a gsp page. I check to see if the value is equal to one of the values in the grails select, and if it is then I set this "current" value as the value appearing in the select box.

Here is my gsp...

```
<g:formRemote name="custom_status" url="[controller: 'traffic', action: 'status']">
  <h4>
    <g:select id="statusId" name="MyStatus" from="${Status.getAllEnums()}" value="${statusValue}" noSelection="['':'Please Select...']" onload="selectedStatus()" onchange="document.getElementById('sub_status').value = ''"/>
  </h4>
    <g:textField name="sub_status" value="${subStatusValue}" />
    <g:submitButton name="submit_status" value="Apply Status" />
  </g:formRemote>
```

The select box changes as desired in Firefox but no change occurs in Chrome.

Here is the resulting HTML...

```
<form onsubmit="jQuery.ajax({type:'POST',data:jQuery(this).serialize(), url:'/portal/traffic/status',success:function(data,textStatus){},error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){}});return false" method="post" action="/portal/traffic/status" id="custom_status">
  <h4>
    <select name="status" id="statusId" onload="selectedStatus()" onchange="document.getElementById(&#39;sub_status&#39;).value = &#39;&#39;" >

<option value="">Please Select...</option>

<option value="available" >available</option>

<option value="away" >away</option>

<option value="dnd" >dnd</option>

<option value="unavailable" >unavailable</option>

</select>
  </h4>
    <input type="text" name="sub_status" value="In a meeting" id="sub_status" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit_status" value="Apply Status" id="submit_status" />
  </form>
  <br/>
```

Thanks

Comment: "Some server side code doesn't work in a particular browser" isn't a very good question. Break it down into either "Some server side code doesn't produce the client side code I expect" or "Some client side code doesn't work in a particular browser".

Comment: What result HTML do you have for this code?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov I get a select box with a list of status's in it. After a refresh, in firefox the status will be whatever I set my status too, in chrome it stays at the default value for no selection.

Comment: @chuckliddell0 i mean source `html`, as a code, not what you see in browser

Comment: @IgorArtamonov I have added in the source above. Thanks for your interest!

Comment: If it's HTML, it shouldn't work. HTML doensn't have such tags as `g:select`, etc. Maybe it's your GSP, not HTML? Try `right click->page source`, or `Ctrl+U`/`Command+U` in Firefox

Comment: @IgorArtamonov Yes it's in gsp and the parameters are being passed into the gsp page from a groovy (grails) controller. Sorry I should have stated this earlier.

Comment: Yes, i understand. But you've said that you have problem on client side, in browsers. GSP is for server side, HTML for client side. By processing your GSP, grails makes a HTML, and if you have different behaivour in different browser, then it's only because of HTML, and it's easier to find a problem looking at a result HTML

Comment: @IgorArtamonov Ahh sorry, I'm fairly new to the programming scene :) I have added the HTML source above, hope this makes things clearer.

Comment: Thanks. I was sure that `g:select` have already marked an option as selected (it should, actually), and you don't need any JS for such task. Ok, can you show also your result JavaScript (from HTML view)?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov When I look at it from the HTML view I do not see any JS, even when I use FireBug. Is there another way of viewing the resultant JS? My original JS from the GSP is at the top of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really strange why `value="${statusValue}"` doesn't work here. Btw, your Javascript code maybe invalid (i'm not sure what you have as a result JS, but it's very likely), so try following:

```
<g:javascript>
    j(document).ready(function ()
    {
      j("#statusId").val('${statusValue}'); //I guess `j` is your prefix for jQuery, right?
    });
</g:javascript>
```

and remove `onload="selectedStatus()"`

Comment: This works great in firefox, but like my original solution, it does not work in chrome. When I refresh the page in chrome it goes back to the `noSelection` value. Thanks though. I can pass `value="${statusValue}"` to the gsp page via a `g:textField` without any problem, it only seems to not work in the `g;select`

Comment: Any js errors in chrome console? `Command + Option + I`, before opening the page

Comment: Nope the console is empty, no errors. This is a weird one haha

Comment: Weird :( maybe JS is disabled in Chrome? :)

Comment: What if try something like `j("#statusId").val('dnd')` directly from JS consoler?

Comment: JS is enabled. Yes this works, the select option changes, so it seems to be able to set it. Does this mean the problem is specifically with `value="${statusValue}"`?

Comment: `value="${statusValue}"` should be working w/o any JS, it should generate HTML with `<option selected="selected"> tags. I've updated my answer, try new version